# How to disable Mission Control shortcut?

Tags: mission-control

I often use IDE's for editing and the shortcut for mission control interferes with my shortcuts within aptana and or other editors.

Is there a way to disable the apple shortcut (<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>▲</kbd>) for osx 10.8.2 ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Go to:  System Preferences-> Mission Control and choose "-" in Mission Control shortcut [image]